# c# Change title bar color for Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I want to made this as in blog post *[How do I apply custom color to the title bar in Windows 10 Universal apps?](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/10/09/how-to-apply-custom-color-to-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-universal-apps/)*.

But this method is for a [Universal Windows Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps) (UWP) application and my project is for Windows Forms, that can work for Windows 7 and newer, but if it runs on Windows 10 I would like to change the color of the title bar.

The specific color is RGB (R 255, G 141, B 105).

Comment: You can mimic this in WinForms by creating a borderless window and mimicking the title bar, icon and control box. It is a bit involved because you have do program dragging the form, resizing, etc. It would an extensive answer to go over it all. Using P/Invoke to draw outside of the client area, is easier, but won't be portable (Edit: although you only want modern versions of Windows, so this shouldn't be a problem) and it can be harder to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing in Windows Forms. Basically, everything you can draw is inside of the client area, which is the forms bounds except the borders and the title bar.

[image]

The border and title bar stuff is called the non-client-area and [even if it is possible, it is not fun to paint in there](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/repainting-non-client-areas/184416783), because you have to care for a lot of stuff like activated/deactivated windows, mouse-effects and of course Windows-version specific things like [Aero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) effects, the DWM manager, visual effects (available or not), RDP/Citrix and other remote/virtualization rendering settings, etc.

If you want to know more about the non-client-area, check out *[Vista Aero ToolStrip on Non-Client Area](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32623/Vista-Aero-ToolStrip-on-Non-Client-Area)*.

There's a thing you can do quite quickly without third-party libraries, but it is quite hard to do right, be warned: Creating a borderless form (`FormBoderStyle=None`) and handle things by yourself, like resizing. Then you have the full control of your form and its title. The good thing: No [PInvokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) for painting in the non-client-area.

The downside is that you have to handle the resizing, minimizing, maximizing, and closing all by yourself. And don't underestimate that; there are several ways to maximize a form, for example: Can you handle all of them? So, there's the click on the "Maximize" button, a doubleclick on your title bar or dragging the title bar to the top of the screen. These are things you have to know and support in the future.

Maybe Windows comes up with new ways, and you have to reimplement then or your users will blame you one day.

There are approaches on the web, [like this one](https://danny.gg/creating-a-borderless-form-with-csharp/), for example. I tried some of them in the past (google for "C# custom title bar" for example). Most of them work and are good on first look, but I never found a 100% complete project.

Another approach is - and I hope you will choose that one - going for 3rd party libraries which already have made their way through the PInvoke-mud and implemented some custom forms you can use. In my opinion the [DevExpress Windows Forms Suite](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/) is the most advanced component suite for Windows Forms, but it comes at a price. I used the [Krypton Toolkit](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton) a lot as well, in meantime it got open source. It's very good and well-thought-out but does not offer the feature richness of DevExpress by far. There are more suites like from [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) or [Infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms).

However they all come with a huge load of features you might not need at all. But they deliver beautiful forms with custom title bars (most of them skinnable) you can edit by yourself (I don't know of this is true for Telerik and Infragistics).

So my recommendation is to evaluate which feature set you need to have and what you want to pay for components (if any). Then you can decide which library you can go for. From the feature rich suites of DevExpress down to smaller projects like Krypton or even to very individual projects with a smaller focus, like [Material Skin](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin) for example. The latter is a very beautiful and unique set of controls (and a custom form) to achieve the Material design from Google. This is very cool, however if you plan to build a business application with powerful grids and reports, Material Skin is too slim for you.